# How to convert date format from YYYY-DD-MM to DD-MM-YYYY

Tags: javascript

I have a date as 2014-12-03

I need to convert this to  DD-MM-YYYY

I have tried as

```
var from = "2014-12-03"; 
var numbers = from.match(/\d+/g); 
var date = new Date(numbers[2], numbers[0]-1, numbers[1]);
alert(date);
```

This is my jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/bnz9d6gz/

Could anybody please help me .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cut your date string into 3 pieces, reverse order, and glue it back

```
"2014-12-03".split('-').reverse().join('-'); // "03-12-2014"
```

**Breakdown:**

1. `"2014-12-03"`       - string
2. `['2014','12','03']` - create an array by splitting each string which isn't `-`
3. `['03','12','2014']` - reversing the array
4. `"03-12-2014"`       - joining all items in the array and putting `-` between them.

Comment: That's nice. Missed, ISO is backwards german date ;) +1 for that simple (and still cool) solution

Comment: people see the word "date" and their brains start to think in misleading ways. you must first examine the problem at it's core, which is text-based. you have a string and you want it to look different. So javascript date object has nothing to do with this question actually and all that's left is simple, JS code which we all write 10 times a day.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
var from = "2014-12-03"; 

function convert(date){
    var d=new Date(date);
    function addLeadingZero(d){
        return (d<10)?"0"+d:d;
    }
    return [d.getDay(), d.getMonth()+1, d.getFullYear()].map(addLeadingZero).join("-");
}

console.log(convert(from));
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bnz9d6gz/1/) updated.

Answer (score -1):

If I were you I'd use [momentJS](http://momentjs.com/), it'll handle this kind of thing for you.  If you pull in the library all you'll need to do is:

```
var from = moment("2014-12-03", "YYYY-MM-DD");
var date = moment.format("DD/MM/YYYY");
alert(date);
```

Much easier than trying to roll your own solution and if you ever need to support additional formats it'll make your life easy.